# UIScreen's nativeBounds tells the wrong resolution for 4K TV

Tags: native, tvos, bounds

I have an Apple TV 4K (tvOS 11.1) connected to a 4K TV display and set Apple TV to 4K SDR 60Hz in Settings.

When I print `[UIScreen mainScreen].nativeBounds`, it prints out 1920x1080 instead of 3840x2160.

Does anyone know why ?

Answer (score 1):

This is expected: bounds is reported in points, not pixels. When running on a 4K display, tvOS considers that display to be a "Retina" (2x) version of a 1080p display. So the bounds size will be the same, but the `.scale` of the screen will be `2.0` on 4K instead of `1.0` on 1080p.